# Issue with POST JSON data Titanium

Tags: json, post, titanium-mobile

I want to post JSON data using HTTP request. I have read the official [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Handling_Remote_Data_with_HTTPClient_and_JSON) and I am working according to them. I am using the following code:

```
var xhrpost = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

    xhrpost.onload = function(){
        activityIndicator.hide();
        alert('Posted successfully');
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
    }

    var posturl = 'http://qudova.com/api.php';

    xhrpost.open('POST', posturl);
    xhrpost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhrpost.setRequestHeader('charset','utf-8');
        var params = {
        ProjectID : picked_prj, 
        RoleID : picked_rol,
        FirstName: first.value,
        LastName: last.value,  
        Phone: phone.value,
        Email: email.value,
        City: city.value,
        State: stat_drp.getSelectedRow(0).title,
        Zip: zip.value,
        Notes: notes.value,
    };
    xhrpost.send(params);
```

If this is the correct way to post the JSON data. How would I check that data is posted ?? Will the url contain the posted data ??

I am getting null in the following alert that I added in the onload event.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
```

I am working on Windows 7 , Testing on Android 4.2.2 .... Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9):

When you set Content-Type to json, you need to stringify the input.

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.open('POST', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader('charset','utf-8');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    prop: 'string',
    data: {
        embeddedProp: 1234
    }
}));
```

Tried this out and it worked, wasn't able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: I've been struggling with the same problem, thank you for your answer. I don't undertand how come stuff like this is not documented...

Answer (score 1):

Just use JSON.stringify()

`JSON.stringify({
        ProjectID : picked_prj, 
        RoleID : picked_rol,
        FirstName: first.value,
        LastName: last.value,

        Phone: phone.value,
        Email: email.value,
        City: city.value,
        State: stat_drp.getSelectedRow(0).title,
        Zip: zip.value,
        Notes: notes.value,
    })`

See [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Working_with_JSON_Data) updated.

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.parse

```
var params =JSON.parse({
        ProjectID : picked_prj, 
        RoleID : picked_rol,
        FirstName: first.value,
        LastName: last.value,  
        Phone: phone.value,
        Email: email.value,
        City: city.value,
        State: stat_drp.getSelectedRow(0).title,
        Zip: zip.value,
        Notes: notes.value,
    })
```

and send it . It may work...